# What is wrong with count

Tags: sql, vb.net

I would like to redirect admin if there is no record in table to the another form but I am doing something wrong in my code but i cant find. Could you please help me?

```
Private Sub frmlogin_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim cmd As SqlCeCommand
    Dim namecount As String
    Dim con1 As SqlCeConnection
    con1 = New SqlCeConnection("Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=.\database.sdf;Password=***********;File Mode=shared read")
    con1.Open()
    namecount = "SELECT COUNT(Name) WHERE namecount FROM Users"
    cmd = New SqlCeCommand("SELECT COUNT(Name) WHERE namecount FROM Users", con1)

    Dim reader1 As SqlCeDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    While (reader1.Read())
        If reader1(namecount) > 0 Then
            'Redirect to Admin Form
            Me.Hide()
            frmadmin.Show()
        Else
            Me.Show()
        End If
    End While
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You meant to use an alias:

```
SELECT COUNT(Name) AS namecount FROM Users
```

instead of

```
SELECT COUNT(Name) WHERE namecount FROM Users
```

And:

```
reader1("namecount")
```

instead of:

```
reader1(namecount)
```

Answer (score 0):

should be

```
SELECT COUNT(Name) AS namecount  FROM Users
```

not

```
SELECT COUNT(Name) WHERE namecount FROM Users
```